# Flutter - How to dismiss a showDialog widget in the middle

Tags: flutter, showdialog

I have two simultaneous processes run independently between each other on the same context. Let's name it A and B. Both popup a busy indicator.

```
showDialog(... child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) ...);
```

On finish, B will popup an `AlertDialog`. Sometimes if A take longer, the alert dialog popup before busy indicator of A is dismissed. So when A finished, it will dismiss the alert dialog not the busy indicator.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(data);
```

How to choose which `showDialog` widget to dismiss?

Answer (score 4):

May be something like this may work:

```
     final GlobalKey navigator1 = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
     final GlobalKey navigator2 = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

     ...

     _showDialog(context, 'alert1', navigator1);
     _showDialog(context, 'alert2', navigator2);

      ...

    _showDialog(BuildContext context, String text, GlobalKey key) {
      return showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      key: key,
                      title: new Text(text),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        new FlatButton(
                          child: new Text("Close"),
                          onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(key.currentContext);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
            });
        }
```

You give a navigator key for each dialog and use that key to dismiss the dialog you want.

Hope it helps