# Flutter - Navigator pop not dismiss showDialog widget according to specified context

Tags: flutter

I have two stacked `Scaffold`s, a parent and a child. On button press, both `Scaffold`s show a popup each from their own context. But no matter what, `Navigator.pop` always dismiss the top most popup, ignoring the passed context.

```
class StateTest extends State<ScreenTest>{

  BuildContext parent, child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    drawer : Drawer(child: Container()),
    body: Builder(builder : (BuildContext context){
      this.parent = context;
      return Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder : (BuildContext context){
          this.child = context;
        }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(context: parent, child: Center(child: Text('PARENT')));
            showDialog(context: child, child: Center(child: Text('CHILD')));
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => Navigator.of(parent).pop());
          }
        ),
      );
    })
  );
}
```

I just want to dismiss popup from specific context.

Comment: You could try setting the rootNavigator parameter to true for the pop of the parent. I haven't tested it though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548153/flutter-navigator-ofcontext-pop-vs-navigator-popcontext-difference

Comment: tried it. not working either

Comment: Can I ask why you are nesting scaffolds? It is not generally recommended. See:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html  in the trouble shooting section.

Comment: actually this is my original problem. i thought i could solve it by stacking the scaffolds but not. let me try separate their states to see how it's going
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590939/flutter-how-to-dismiss-a-showdialog-widget-in-the-middle

Comment: If I read that correctly, A and B run concurrently, both show a busy progress indicator but only B shows the alert dialogue. Is that right? If so, then why don't you wait for both to finish before showing the alert dialogue. Or you can set a 'busy' bool in both processes and only clear it when B finishes in a  call to  setState() {}. Then show your busy progress indicator until 'busy' is false.

Comment: actually it is an example. the idea is to keep the busy circle always at the top. i thought with stacked `Scaffold`s, busy circle from outer `Scaffold` will always overlay everything from inner `Scaffold`, like it does to other `Scaffold`'s components. that is before i came up with this question

Comment: Ok so to display the spinner on top use Stack() and make the circular progress indicator one of the child widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigator.of(context)` gets the closest `Navigator`  parent widget.

Both `parent` and `child` context refer to the same `navigator` so both dialogs are pushed to the same navigator and the last dialog is the one popped

The way to do it is adding a new navigator:

- The dialog you want to show closer to the user is has to be the farthest navigator. In our case the root navigator
- The dialog that will be display between the scaffold and the other dialog should be pushes from the new created navigator

**See [online demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1c5ec42184009f0302e4e32d5d43ec40)**

```dart
class StateTest extends State<ScreenTest>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
    Navigator(
         onGenerateRoute: _getRoute
  );

  Route _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name){
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(body: Container(), floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(context: context, child: Center(child: Text('PARENT')), useRootNavigator: false);
            showDialog(context: context, child: Center(child: Text('CHILD')), );
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => Navigator.of(context).pop());
          }
        ));
        });
      default:
        return null;
    }

  }

}
```

A drawing explaining the widget tree

[image: example]

Comment: without testing it first I'm sure this is the answer I'm looking for. thank you sir